# java get several columns with hibernate SQLQuery

Tags: java, database, hibernate, select, sql-query-store

i'm using SQLQuery to select some data from database using hibernate.
when trying to select * it works but when need only several columns it returns:Invalid column name
searched other topics about this issue but didn't helped;
here is my code:

User.java where is declared variables:

public class User implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ")

private Integer id;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String firstname;
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String lastname;
@Column(name = "DATE_OB", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String birthdate;
@Column(name = "DATE_OW", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String startdate;
@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String department;
@Column(name = "POSITION", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String position;
```

//with getters and setter

part from where trying to select:

```
public static List<User> getAllUser()
{
    List<User> result = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "select first_name from employee";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery   (sql).addEntity(User.class);
        result = query.list();



    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;

}
```

As i guess i don't need to create separate hibernate-mapping file, because its already done in User class.
Please help to find out what can be reason.

Comment: You're selecting the first name, but you expect to get User objects out of it? It doesn't work that way. A first name is not a `User`, it's a `String`.

Comment: now tried to change <User> with <String> and after with <Object> but result was same, how can it be fixed?

Comment: Don't put `addEntity()` in there because you're not retrieving an entity.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. removed addEntity and worked all casese.

Comment: You should mark my answer as correct then, to give some closure to this question (and sweet sweet StackOverflow points to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're loading data with a native query (as it's called in JPA world), you can either load full entities when querying all the columns, i.e. `SELECT * FROM foo` or you can load one or more separate columns, which result in getting a `Object[]` or some specific type (such as `String`).

Here you're trying to load just the first name as a `User` entity, presumably hoping that the other fields would be left blank. However that's not how it works. Either you load a full entity, or an array of specified column values.

Something like the following should work

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List<String> names = query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks, at first it didn't work but after removing addEntity() it worked with  List<String> and with List<User>
it seems i didn't fully understand how addEntity()  works and where it have to use.
I added addEntity() because, without it result was massive of objects:
[[300,"John","Doe","01-01-1980","05-11-2011","Development","Senior"]

but after added addEntity() it looked like this:
'[{"id":300,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","birthdate":"01-01-1980","startdate":"05-11-2011","department":"Development","position":"Senior"}]'

Comment: Well that's the difference between retrieving an entity and just parts of the data for the entity.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

List first_names = query.list();

for (Object object : first_names) 
         {
          System.out.println("User Details are==========  " + object);  
        // or
          Map map = (Map) object;
          System.out.println("first_names : " + map.get("first_name"));
         }
```